# Grid row auto-size relative sizing issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm a relative WPF newbie and am still trying to get my head around its basics. I have just came across a grid sizing issue which has me stumped (and it seems that is not limited to just grids alone).

The problem is that if I have a grid with relatively sized rows/columns, within a row/column of another grid, with that row/column dimensions being set to auto, the relative sizing for the child grid seems to have no effect.

[image]

What I would expect for this xaml, is that the inner grid columns are still relatively sized (with one being 3x the width of the other) even if they are inside an auto-sized column of parent grid. Is this expected behaviour, is this a bug or am I missing something basic?

Thanks!!

Comment: please insert your code as text, not as screenshot of editor

Comment: Yes, this is default behavior. `Auto` means just needed minimum. And as it is set in outer `Grid` it takes precedence.

Comment: Why don't you just have the first grid with 3 columns and get rid of the inner grid?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Just wondering why is code preferred in written form over an image? I thought this was a good candidate for an image as it shows code and designer side by side.

Comment: It makes sense that auto should get the minimum... but does that not break a lot of basic functionality? Basic CSS supports this kind of case just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems outer Grid column dictate which width inner Grid should have. Try reverse measure order by binding column width to inner grid width: `<ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=InnerGrid}"/>`

```
<Grid Background="DarkBlue">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=InnerGrid}"/>            
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Cell 1" />

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Name="InnerGrid" Background="DarkRed">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Cell 2.1" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Cell 2.2" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

after resize only 1st column is increasing (see screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Oh wow thanks! That's exactly what I was trying to do! :D

Is it just me or does it seem a little strange that this is the way WPF handles auto-sizing? Coming from CSS this seems quite complicated for such a basic function.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
   <Grid Background="DarkBlue">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label BorderBrush="White"
               BorderThickness="1"
               Content="Cell 1"
               Foreground="White" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label BorderBrush="White"
                   BorderThickness="1"
                   Content="Cell 2"
                   Foreground="White" />

            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   BorderBrush="White"
                   BorderThickness="1"
                   Content="Cell 3"
                   Foreground="White" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

The reason that second grid was behaving strangely is because the column of the first grid is set to Auto.
As it's auto it's trying to squash everything inside it to be as small as possible - without the labels this would be a width of 0 for each column of the second grid. Plus the width of the labels makes them about equal.

I believe it has something to do with the order in which WPF calculates widths of something in an auto column/row.

The first thing it does is notice the auto value of the second grid, which is 0. THEN, after that it adds whatever the width of the contents are to this calculated value - as both labels are about the same size, this results in two similar columns.

My solution removes the auto value and instead says the the first column of the first grid "of the total width, you get 2/3rds of the space, and the other column gets 1/3rd" - it's not auto, so the second column is not being squashed in any way.

Comment: Thanks! That's what we ended up going with before I posted the question :)

I think my interpretation of Auto was quite different. I thought auto just changed the container size to fit the child, while in reality it seems to disregard any child sizing and squash anything right down, which seems quite weird....

Comment: @Ross Precisely. StackPanels work in a very similar way.